# python class inheritance: constructor of derived class issue

Tags: python, class, inheritance, constructor, derived

I have two classes: a base class A and the derived class B. In the constructor of B I tried to use the constructor of A to initialize the instance. Why assignment "self = A(x)" in constructor of the derived class does not work?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        print "constructing A"
        self.x = x

    def printx(self):
        print "x =",self.x 

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,x):
        A.__init__(self)
        print "constructing B"
        self = A(x)
        self.printx()


b = B(2)
b.printx()
```

The output:

```
constructing A
constructing B
constructing A
x = 2
x = 0
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? ie, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to call the constructor in `B.__init__`, and you should pass `x` to `A.__init__`

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        print "constructing A"
        self.x = x
    def printx(self):
        print "x =",self.x 

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,x):
        A.__init__(self, x)
        print "constructing B"
        self.printx()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, think of variable names (like `self`) as "pointing at" or "referencing" values. When you make an instance of `B`:

```
b = B(2)
```

The `B.__init__` method is called with the variable `self` already assigned to the inchoate instance of `B`. Now, inside this method, when Python reaches

```
        self = A(x)
```

the variable `self` gets reassigned to a new instance of `A`. The instance of `B` still exists; `self` just no longer points to it.

Note that `self` is a variable like any other in Python. (`self` is not a keyword, it is only a convention that the first argument to methods is called `self`.)

---

By the way, to initialize `self` with the value of `x`, use

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,x):
        A.__init__(self, x)    # <-- Note the x
        print "constructing B"
        self.printx()
```

Then

```
b = B(2)
b.printx()
```

yields

```
constructing A
constructing B
x = 2
x = 2
```

---

When a class has an alternate constructor, such as `getA`, a typical pattern in Python is to use a classmethod:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        print "constructing A"
        self.x = x

    def printx(self):
        print "x =",self.x 

    @classmethod
    def getA(cls, x):
        print('constructing getA')
        self = cls(x)
        self.y = 1
        return self
```

Now to make an instance of `A` with the classmethod `getA`, you'd say

```
a = A.getA(x)
```

The class `A` is passed as the first argument to the classmethod `getA`, and stored in the variable `cls`.

What is beautiful about doing it this way (instead of using a factory function `getA`), is that if you subclass `A` like this:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,x):
        A.__init__(self, x)
        print "constructing B"
        self.printx()
```

then you can make instances of `B` using the `getA` classmethod as well:

```
b = B.getA(2)
```

yields

```
constructing getA
constructing A
constructing B
x = 2
```

and

```
print(type(b))
print(b.y)
```

yields

```
<class '__main__.B'>  # b is an instance of B
1   # showing the y attribute has been set.
```

Comment: Thank you @unutbu and @jfaller! So - how can I assign a value to 'self' without it getting reassigned to a new instance of A? The reason I ask is that I have a 'factory' function `getA(x)` that returns an object of type A. Is there any way I can use something like `self = getA(x)` in the constructor of B?

Comment: Don't try to reassign `self`. Instead think of ways to modify `self` (change its attributes). I've edited my post to show one way to do it.